# Assertion Failed: You must include an 'id' for account in an object passed to 'push' Ember.js v-2.4

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, serialization

I'm new to Ember and I can't find anywhere a solution to my problem. I have read the questions here in stack and in other ember forums, but none of them seems to work for me.

I'm trying to create a simple signup form. I should note that for the backend I use django.
Here is my code:

Server Response:

```
[{"username":"user1","password":"123","email":"user1@example.com"},        
{"username":"user2","password":"456","email":"user2@example.com"}]
```

Ember Model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    username: DS.attr(),
    password: DS.attr(), 
    email: DS.attr()
});
```

Ember Adapter: 
    import DS from 'ember-data';

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: '/api',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',

    headers: {
        username: 'XXXX',
        password: 'XXXX'
   } 
});
```

Ember Serializer:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: '_id'
});
```

Ember Route:
    import Ember from 'ember';

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.store.findAll('account');
    }
});
```

Ember Controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

    actions: {

    signup(){
        console.log('My username is: ', this.get('username'));
        console.log('My password is: ', this.get('password'));
        console.log('My email is: ', this.get('email'));

        var account = this.store.createRecord('account', {
                username: this.get('username'),
                password: this.get('password'),
                email: this.get('email')
        });

        account.save();

    }
    }
});
```

With this implementation I get the aforementioned error. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 22):

Your backend should respond with an id, i.e

```
{"id":123,"username":"user1","password":"123","email":"user1@example.com"}
```

You don't really need to use the serializer, unless you want a specific field to act as an id. So in the example above, ember-data would expect your backend to return

```
{**"_id":123**,"username":"user1","password":"123","email":"user1@example.com"}
```

Or you could do something like this:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: 'username'
});
```

And use your username as an id.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Igor, I just couldn't figure out what the server was using as an id.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed my error. The problem was that the backend was using username as id so ember could not recognized it.

The fixed code for the Ember Serializer is:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
     primaryKey: 'username'
});
```